# how to update a existing dataframe from a dictionary with keys as column and values forming the row in a loop

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer    
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for i in range(len(X)):
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(X.loc[i,'essay'])
    X.from_dict(ss)
```

Here X is an existing dataframe and i want to add 4 new columns whose name is key of the dictionary and value will form row.

Using above code i am getting error:

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

But i don't know how to pass index

[image: sample of dataframe] 
Sample dictionary : {'neg': 0.013, 'neu': 0.833, 'pos': 0.154, 'compound': 0.9694}
'neg','neu','pos','compound' needed to added as new column to the existing dataframe and their corresponding value as row

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

from_dict method expects iterable or dict as values of keys.

```
X['neg'],X['neu'],X['pos'],X['compound'] = 'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'

for i in range(len(x)):
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(X.loc[i,'essay'])
    for j,k in ss.items():
        X.loc[i,j] = k
```